# Powershell: Casting to byte array run infinity

Tags: arrays, powershell, casting

I have a 4MB file and decide to load it from Powershell, so below code is executeed

```
[byte[]]$bytes = Get-Content $file -Encoding byte
```

However, this line of code run infinity, doesn't seem to finish & increasingly consume a lot of RAM memory.
Any suggestion for this?

Comment: `Get-Content $file -Encoding byte -Raw`

Comment: Thank you. It worked! What's the reason which makes -Raw argument fix the memory issue ?

Comment: `-Raw` read file at once rather than byte at once.

Comment: @PetSerAl Nice one. Please consider posting as answer so it can be marked as such and removed from unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `-Encoding Byte` without `-Raw`, then `Get-Content` will write each individual byte as separate object. `Get-Content` also adds some extra properties to each object. That leads to very substantial memory overhead per object (1.4KB+ in my testing (x64, v5.1)). So that, you need something like 6GB of memory to load 4MB file like that. And if that do not fit into RAM, then you will have heavy swapping, which make the process very slow. With `-Raw` `Get-Content` will read whole file as single `[Byte[]]`, which greatly reduce overhead per byte.

Comment: Perfect explanation!